# Animation Drawable: I would like to get the resorce name of the drawable being shown by the animation as it is runnig

Tags: android, animation

EX: During the animation when a user clicks a Button I want to know which image was being displayed at that time. Any way to get the resorce name or ID or something I can trace back to the resorce name of the image. I have looked with in the ANIMATION DRAWABLE class and there is a getter that returns a drawable but I  amnot able to related to the name of the image I have set. I am also quite new to Android and programming.

Animation list example

```
   <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
   android:oneshot="true">

  <item android:drawable="@drawable/fix" android:duration="800" /> 
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/lllllup_nc" android:duration="1700" /> 
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/blank" android:duration="1000" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try comparing the drawables instead of trying to get the related name to compare. You would have to compare names anyway.

So you can get the current drawable frame using 'drawableanimationname'.getCurrent()
You can get the drawable of each frame with 'drawableanimationname'.getFrame('index')

Since you know which resource corresponds to which frame index (0-2 in your case), you can then check by seeing if the current frame == the getFrame at that index.

Comment: I am actually not trying to compare it to something else. I just need to know the exact resorce name when I make some kind of request as the animation is runnig. thaks for the help and sorry if perhaps I did not understad

Comment: Updated for clarity now

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarity. At the click of a button I addded a loop to check to which frame number the current drwable is equal to as Whitney suggested:  getCurrent() == getFrame(position). It works great.